# Pointing to coordinates

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to do an arrow that points to a certain position but the problem is that when I do an angle with the vectors he can't make the difference between west and east because it's 90° in both. How can I make the west negative or add it 180° to make the difference between them ?

My code:

```
double angle = 0;       
Vector a = (targetLoc).toVector().subtract(player.getLocation().toVector()).normalize();
Vector b = player.getLocation().getDirection();
angle = Math.acos(a.dot(b));
angle = Math.toDegrees(angle);
```

targetLoc is the position I want to point

For example when the coordinates are at 90° from the vision from the player the angle is 90° in west side and on est side or when the coordinates are at 45° from the vision from the player the angle is 45° in west side and on est side.

I want only to use the x and z plan not the y.

Comment: This is untested code, but you could do something like look at the `asin` to see if it's supposed to be positive or negative `angle = Math.asin(a.dot(b)) >= 0 ? Math.acos(a.dot(b)) : -Math.acos(a.dot(b));`

Comment: Could you provide a sample input/output for your program?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: Let me introduce you to [the `atan2` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) - it's literally for this kind of thing, and is so basic-but-crucial-to-everything-mathy that most CPUs even have it baked-in as dedicated instruction.

Comment: How can I use it with vectors ?

Comment: I want only to use the x and z plan not the y.

Comment: Well, you're using Java, so I'd suggest looking up the API documention for the `java.lang.Math.atan2` method? If you just want to work with and `x and z`, then you can do that just fine. `atan2` needs two deltas, based on the difference between two vectors, in two dimensions. It doesn't care what you call those dimensions =)

Comment: I'm going to see that thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done thank you for your help

```
        Vector a = (targetLoc).toVector().subtract(player.getLocation().toVector()).normalize();
        Vector b = player.getLocation().getDirection();
        angle = Math.acos(a.dot(b));
        angle = Math.toDegrees(angle);
        if(a.getX()*b.getZ() - a.getZ()*b.getX() < 0) {
            angle = -angle;
        }
```